SELECT on a specific partition key does not return data
Problem Description:
We have a table in Cassandra version 3.11.7. After migrating three nodes to another availability zone, I encountered an issue where I cannot retrieve data by the primary key, despite the data being successfully inserted.
Table schema:
CREATE TABLE m_operational.app_settings (
    endpoint_id text PRIMARY KEY,
    format text,
    settings_json text,
    platform text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

Select query that i trying to execute:
select * from m_operational.app_settings where endpoint_id='endpoint-i-need';

And I get nothing even after insert query:
INSERT INTO m_operational.app_settings (endpoint_id, format, settings_json, platform) VALUES( 'endpoint-i-need', 'free', '{""settings"": ""my-settings""}', 'PC');

tried to create a similar record next to it but with a different key - everything worked:
INSERT INTO m_operational.app_settings (endpoint_id, format, settings_json, platform) VALUES( 'endpoint-i-need1', 'free', '{""settings"": ""my-settings""}', 'PC');
select * from m_operational.app_settings where endpoint_id='endpoint-i-need1';

This problem started to arise during the migration of 3 Cassandra nodes from one availability zone to another and remains to this day (There are 9 nodes in the cluster).
The migration was carried out as follows:

Creation of new nodes and adding to the existing cluster
Reconfiguration of services to use new nodes
Decommission and removal of old nodes

After migration I execute nodetool cleanup on each of the nodes and then ran a repair with the command nodetool repair --full -pr -j 2 on each of the nodes. Nothing has changed and the select still doesn't work. Then I tried to run repair for a specific table on all nodes with nodetool repair --full -pr -j 2 m_operational app_settings - that didn't help either.
What can I look at in Cassandra to understand the cause of the problem? or how can i fix this problem?

Could you show the output of running DESCRIBE KEYSPACE m_operational; here? Was the new nodes added to the existing datacenter/region or as a separate datacenter/region? [I got confused by this Reconfiguration of services to use new nodes as the clients come to know of the entire topology after connecting just to the initial contact point nodes]. And btw, for repairs, it is always recommended to use nodetool repair -pr on one node at a time across the entire cluster nodes (or leave that to tools like reaper to take care of it automatically).

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

My best guess is that someone deleted the partition with a timestamp set in the future so the tombstone has a later date than any of the INSERT statements you issue.
This would be simple to prove with a bit of investigation. First is to identify the replicas which own the partition with:
$ nodetool getendpoints -- m_operational app_settings <pkey>

Then for each of the replicas, identify the SSTables which contains the partition with:
$ nodetool getsstables -- m_operational app_settings <pkey>

Go through the contents of each SSTable using sstabledump and look for a tombstone, particularly the deletion date/time:
$ sstabledump -k <pkey> /path/to/data/.../...Data.db

WARNING - sstabledump is an offline tool. Cassandra must be stopped before using the utility otherwise the node's normal operation may be compromised.
When you identify the SSTable(s) that contains the "future" tombstone, you will need to move it (and its corresponding components like *-Statistics.db, *-Index.db, etc) out of the data directory since there is no way to remove tombstones with a deletion time set for the future. Cheers!

Yes, you are right, thank you - that's what happened, I found a record with deletion in the future. But I doubt moving the ss table files from the data directory, I'm afraid that this can somehow damage the data in the table. Do you know if this can happen or I shouldn't be afraid?

And if it is not dangerous, then should I do it at once on all nodes where the broken files are located at the same time? or can I move these files one node at a time?

Yes, it could be dangerous because it could lead to data loss so you'll need to do an analysis of the data on each replica. Hopefully, the SSTables don't all contain the same partitions. Otherwise, you'll need to manually re-load the data by reconstructing INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements from the output of sstabledump. Cheers!
